# Laravel error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: php, laravel

The full error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'quotesapp.admin' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `admin` where `username` = Admin)
```

I know the error is the mismatch between the name as it appears in the error log and how it's defined everywhere else (in the database folder, but I am unable to solve the problem. I searched around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159257/base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-laravel-5) post, but even after I implemented the solution(shown below), I keep getting the same error.

I am using Laravel 5.2. I have an `admins` table in my database directory which looks like this:

```
class CreateAdminsTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('admins');
    }
}
```

The Admin model looks like this :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable; 

class Admin extends Model implements \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'admins';
    use Authenticatable;
}

?>
```

Here is the relevant route that is causing the error to be thrown:

```
Route::post('/admin/register', [
    'uses' => 'AdminController@postRegister',
    'as' => 'register'
]);
```

And here is the `postRegister` method

```
 public function postRegister(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|unique:admin|max:30|min:3',
        'password' => 'required|min:5',
        'password_confirm' => 'required'           
    ]);

    $password = $request['password'];
    $passwordConfirm = $request['password_confirm'];

    if ($password !== $passwordConfirm) {
        return redirect()->back()->with(['fail' => 'password fields do not match!']);
    }

    $admin = new Admin();
    $admin->username = $request['username'];
    $admin->password = $request['password'];
    $admin->save();

    return redirect()->route('index');       

}
```

I have run `php artisan migrate` in composer, but I get the "nothing to migrate" response. I have tried refreshing the database via composer, but to no avail. The table 'admins' is showing up in phpmyadmin.

**Update 1:** Added full error message

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error comes from the validation part:

```
  $this->validate($request, [
    'username' => 'required|unique:admin|max:30|min:3',
    'password' => 'required|min:5',
    'password_confirm' => 'required'           
]);
```

When checking for uniqueness of the `username` you're referring to the `admin` table in the database, however the table is called `admins` (with a **s** at the end).
Therefore Laravel is looking for a table called `admin` which of course doesn't exist. Add the **s** at the end and it should work.

Comment: @Frosty619 I too believe this to be the case. change `unique:admin` to `unique:admins` and let us know if this works.

Comment: Hi @Maximilian Schwarzmüller You are a life saver, I read all repeating solutions but this line just saved my life: `error comes from the validation part`. Wow

Answer (score 3):

Try to add `protected $table = 'admins';` to Admin model after trait.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "after trait"? I did add the line you suggested after 'use Authenticatable;' in my Admin model, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if relevant but I got that message because my model was a different name to Db table.  You can add a protected table name in model if it isn't the plural of the model.

Comment: Add the protected table name in the model class.  Like mentioned below: protected $table = 'admins';  at the top of your admin model

Answer (score 1):

Laravel is telling you it cannot find such table.

`dd()` is your friend.

```
$admin = new Admin();
dd($admin);
```

Check what's the table it has on properties, and it will point you in the right way.

Assuming your DB config is properly setup??

Also, when you migrate a DB, and it runs a class, it stores the step in the migrations table.

So, if you want to migrate something more, the point is you make another migration.

To make changes, use the `Schema::table` method.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and I get the following response "Class app\Admin is not defined", which is super weird because Admin is defined in the app folder.

Comment: Change it to \App\Admin