# How to use join in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have following two tables.

```
users - id,name,title
posts - id,author
```

where `post.author = user.id`

My Post model as follows.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

I use `Project::find(1)->users`

But it giving following error.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found.
```

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `Post::find(1)->users` ?

Comment: You need to read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one). By default, Laravel assumes the id would be `user_id` in the `posts` table. If you want to use the `author` column name, then you may override that in your `User` model.

Comment: @Daan yes it is.changed it.but not works.

Comment: Thanks @Krik Bread. Is this the way? return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Post', 'author');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Post model..

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'author');
    }
}
```

Now use it as..

```
Post::find(1)->users;
```

As because a post have only a single creator you can change the `users` method on `Post` model as `user` and use it as

```
Post::find(1)->user;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code to this:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
       return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'author');
    }
}
```

This will get the user from the database by calling `Post::find(1)->user->id`.

I suggest to change `users` to `user` because a post can have only one author.

Hope this works!

Comment: Post::find(1)->user->id call from PostController.But it's not work.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`author` in (1))

Comment: Ow I see, the arguments are in the wrong order... I update my answer!

Comment: Thanks @Robin Dirksen Now it return string(1) "1" instead of the object

Answer (score 0):

This should change

```
Project::find(1)->users
```

to this

```
Post::find(1)->users
```

---

**Read This**

1. [Base table or view not found: 1146 Table Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159257/base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-laravel-5)