# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'blog.categories' doesn't exist in engine (SQL: select * from `categories`)

Tags: laravel

I had issues with my xampp phpmyadmin, I had to uninstall and reinstall it, after that , I tried copying my files back and running my application but it's not working.

Its giving me

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'blog.categories' doesn't exist in engine (SQL: select * from `categories`)
```

I have tried migration of my files to the database but it's also not working

Here's what it says:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'blog.migrations' doesn't exist in engine (SQL: select `m
  igration` from `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration` asc)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'blog.migrations' doesn't exist in engine
```

Comment: what is your DB name in your `.env` file and in `phpadmin` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159257/base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-laravel-5

Comment: my db name is blog and in phpmyadmin its also blog

Comment: someone pleas help i cant start all over again

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan migrate:fresh`? This will run all migrations all over again, so only use it if there is no valuable information in there

Comment: yes i fixed it with php artisan config:cache

Comment: so the solution was just to clear my cache and migrate again

so i ran php artisan config:cache
after it was cleared
then i ran
php artisan migrate, which fixed it and got all mt table back to my database .

Answer (score 5):

Disconnect all server connections.
Including commands:

```
php artisan serve
```

And stop the Apache server and MySQL database and start again. then run:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try running this before

```
php artisan schema:dump
```

which may conflicted with database migration because it [squashing migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#squashing-migrations) to be executed as sql before any migrations in `database/migration`, try deleting any file in `database/schema` then try run

```
php artisan migrate
```

if the migrate command didn't simply work, try the [Negar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64675358/11163784) answer to help the migration

Answer (score 0):

That means that the DB lost or the base of that database doesn't exist. you must have a backup where you will have to drop and import that same db back then restart to what you wanted to do

or

drop the Database, create the same name and use command:

> php artisan migrate

to return it but all previous data will have been lost and you have to add it manually or via the application again