# Laravel 8 - I got this error 'SQLSTATE[42S02]' how can I solve this?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to do follow system without any laravel libray. I got this error when I submit form. How can I fix it? I think error is about my user model and my follow model relationship but I couldn't solve.

My error is:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'muzik.follows' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `follows`
> (`following_id`, `follower_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
> (12, 30, 2021-04-02 22:32:50, 2021-04-02 22:32:50))

**My User model contains the following relationship:**

```
public function follows(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Follow');
    }
```

**My User model contains the following relationship:**

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
```

**My controller is:**

```
public function follow(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'follower_id'=>['required'],
            'following_id'=>['required'],
        ]);

        $follower_id = $request->follower_id;
        $following_id = $request->following_id;
        

        $save = Follow::create([
            'following_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'follower_id' => $follower_id,
        ]);

        if($save){
            return back();
        }else{
            return back();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Base table or view not found: 1146 Table Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159257/base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-laravel-5)

Comment: yes but I'm beginner in Laravel. i don't know how can I fix this

Answer (score 0):

check your "Follow" model, you may needs specify table name with:
`protected $table='tableWhereYouSaveFollows';`

Comment: i have one more relationship like this follow system in this project and it is working but this model with the relationships not working. I don't know where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your migration I think you did not create the `Follow` table if you did try to Just specify your table in the model as such:

```
class follows extends Model{
    public $table = "follow";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your follow table does not exist, first create your follow table and then add this to your follow model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Follow extends Model
{
    protected $table="follows";
   
    //---Guarded
    protected $guarded = [];

    //---User Function
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```