# \Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.Users' doesn't exist (SQL: truncate table `Users`)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i am trying to run:

php artisan db:seed

and i get this error:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.Users' doesn't exist (SQL: truncate table `Users`)
```

this is the code from databaseseeder.php:

as you can see , i truncate the users table which is created in user.php MODEL, database seeder code here:

```
public function run()
    {
        // \App\Models\User::factory(10)->create();

        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');

        User::truncate();
        Category::truncate();
        Product::truncate();
        Transaction::truncate();
        DB::table('category_product')->truncate();

        $cantidadUsuarios = 200;
        $cantidadCategories = 30;
        $cantidadProductos = 1000;
        $cantidadTransacciones = 1000;

        factory(User::class, $cantidadUsuarios)->create();
        factory(Category::class, $cantidadCategories)->create();

        factory(Category::class, $cantidadTransacciones)->create()->each(
            function ($producto) {
                $categorias = Category::all()->random(mt_rand(1, 5))->pluck('id');
                $producto->categories()->attach($categories->first());
            }
        );
        factory(Transaction::class, $cantidadTransacciones)->create();
    }
}
```

here is the user model class:

as you can see i am defining the table name in:

```
public $table = "Users";
```

the solution came from here: [Base table or view not found: 1146 Table Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159257/base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-laravel-5)

but still does not works, i also... ran `"php artisan migrate"` , to make sure i am not leaving something out,

then i ran php artisan db:seed, however did not worked out,

User.php model class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public $table = "Users";

    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    const USUARIO_VERIFICADO = '1';

    const USUARIO_NO_VERIFICADO = '0';

    const USUARIO_ADMINISTRADOR = 'TRUE';


    const USUARIO_REGULAR = 'FALSE';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'verified',
        'verification_token',
        'admin',

    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'verification_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function esVerificado()
    {
        return $this->verified == User::USUARIO_VERIFICADO;
    }

    public function esAdministrador()
    {
        return $this->verified == User::USUARIO_ADMINISTRADOR;
    }

    public static function generarVerificationToken()
    {
        return str_random(40);
    }
}
```

and also here is the USERS CREATE MIGRATION CLASS:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use App\Models\User;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->string('verified')->default(User::USUARIO_NO_VERIFICADO);
            $table->string('verification_token')->nullable();
            $table->string('admin')->default(User::USUARIO_REGULAR);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

i do not know what i am doing wrong, so i come here seeking for some light from StackOverflow community to help me, since i  do not know what is wrong and i am just starting with laravel,

i submmited all the useful information in order to determine what is the problem

if you need something else please feel free to request it, thank you
thank you

Comment: Table names are case sensitive in MySQL on platforms with case sensitive file systems. So the table might be created as `users` not `Users` and thus `Users` cannot be found later on.

Comment: Try this one: `protected $table = 'users';`

Comment: Are you sure the database name is correct ? `homestead` seems default...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
public $table = "Users";
```

to

```
public $table = "users";
```