# Cant find select * from `bedrijfs`

Tags: laravel

[image: i know its because of a spelling error it should be bedrijven not bedrijfs]

I try to find the source of this error i looked everywhere and i even used the vsc finder to search for the typo... do you know where this is located

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Base table or view not found: 1146 Table Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159257/base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing Laravel isn't able to find your table.

Guessing you're using a model, provide the model with a tablename.
In your model, add:

```
protected $table = 'your_tablename';
```